# Counting in a complex query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I will explain my problem with an example:

***Tables***:
**place** - **comment** - **activities_comment** - **activities**

**User can comment a place and select what kind of activities are being able to do in that place.**
Activities are for example: run, swim, walk and climb.

So **some users would vote more than 1 activity**, so i can't put it right in the same table COMMENT, i need to create a pivote table ACTIVITIES_COMMENT, the problem goes here, i was able to show all the comments with their activities selected in each place..

But now **i want to count the number of activities and order them by the most selected activity to the less selected by the users in the comments for each place.** 
How can I do that??

The best thing i can do is:

```
$place = Place::with('city','comments')
            ->where('id',$placeId)->first();


$place->activities = Activity::join('activities_comment', 'activity.id', '=', 'activities_comment.activity_id')
            ->join('comment', 'comment.id', '=', 'activities_comment.comment_id')
            ->select('comment.id','activities_comment.activity_id',
                DB::raw('(SELECT count(activities_comment.activity_id) FROM activities_comment WHERE activities_comment.activity_id = 1) as run'),
                DB::raw('(SELECT count(activities_comment.activity_id) FROM activities_comment WHERE activities_comment.activity_id = 2) as swim'),
                DB::raw('(SELECT count(activities_comment.activity_id) FROM activities_comment WHERE activities_comment.activity_id = 3) as walk'),
                DB::raw('(SELECT count(activities_comment.activity_id) FROM activities_comment WHERE activities_comment.activity_id = 4) as climb'),
                )
            ->where('comment.place_id',$place->id)
            ->get();
```

The problem is that this query counts the most selected activities but in ALL places, i want to count only in each place.

---

**EDIT**:

Example rows:

**place** table:

```
id | name
----------
1  | Alaska
2  | Peru
3  | Argentina
```

**comment** table:

```
id | user_id | place_id | text
------------------------------------
1  | 1       | 1        | some text
2  | 3       | 1        | some text
3  | 2       | 2        | some text
```

**activity** table:

```
id | name 
----------
1  | run
2  | swim
3  | walk
4  | climb
```

**activity_comment** table:

```
id | comment_id | activity_id
------------------------------
1  | 1          | 1        
2  | 1          | 2        
3  | 2          | 2       
4  | 3          | 2
```

When i get into Alaska comments, i would like to see the times that users selected an activity there, for alaska it will show:

```
run: 1 time
swim: 2 times
walk: 0 times
climb: 0 times
```

If i go to Peru comments:

```
run: 0 times
swim: 1 time
walk: 0 times
climb: 0 times
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you looked at GROUP BY - I am trying to get my head around what you want exactly from your question but the general jist GROUP BY seems to give what you want - can you clarify by adding a small 3/4 row sample of data and what a query should return?

Comment: i will add it in a second.. what i need is to add a conditional in each raw select i think to count the activity only for one place at the time.

Comment: An sqlfiddle (and/or proper DDLs) would sure be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get the tables all linked up via the joins showing how each table is related to the next by their respective keys.  Then, its just a matter of each name (city/location), and name of the activity and getting a count grouped by the respective location and activity.
The order by clause will put all same locations first, then within each location will put the highest count activity secondary... if any have same counts, then the names will be alpha ordered

```
SELECT
      p.name,
      a.name as Activity,
      COUNT(*) as NumComments
   from
      place p
         join comment c
            ON p.id = c.place_id
            join activity_comment ac
               ON c.id = ac.comment_id
               join activity a
                  ON ac.activity_id = a.id
   group by
      p.name,
      a.name
   order by
      p.name,
      COUNT(*) desc,
      a.name
```

Now, you will just need to plug in your WHERE clause (before the group by) for whatever location or activity you may be interested in.